# Is there a standard way to write a for loop that does not need an update statement?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

As we all know, most for loops take on this form:

```
for (int i = 0; i < whatever; i++)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

I am writing a method at the moment where it is not appropriate to include "i++" as in the format above because i is being updated in a loop nested within this loop.  So for now, I have this:

```
List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
PopulateListOfItems(itemList);

List<List<Item>> itemSubListList = new List<List<Item>>();

for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; //i doesn't need updating here)
{
    List<Item> subList = new List<Item>();

    for (int j = 0; j < subListSize && i < itemList.Count; j++)
    {   
        subList.Add(itemList[i++]);
    }

    itemSubListList.Add(subList;
}
```

Is there a standard way to write such a loop, perhaps including some sort of dummy code where i++ would normally go to make it clear no update is needed?  Perhaps something like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < whatever; true)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

... or am I just at the end of a long week and my brain is too fried to realize I really should just be using a while loop or something?

By the way, I've written this in C#, yes, but this can apply to a variety of languages.

Comment: You can omit it, but then you've just written a while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop construct is just syntactic sugar for a while loop, and all for loops decompose into while loops.

```
for(int i = 0; i < whatever; i++)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

ultimately means:

```
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < whatever)
    {
        //do stuff
        i++;
    }
}
```

(note the additional curly braces for scoping of the integer)

Any parts of the for loop that you omit are also omitted from the decomposed while loop and thus you have to handle them manually.  If you don't use all three parts, you really may as well just write a while loop (especially if one of the parts you omitted was the variable initializer, because of the variable scope I mentioned).

Answer (score 8):

Just omit it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < whatever; )
{
    //do stuff
}
```

In fact, all parts of the `for`-loop are optional (in C# at least, this may not be the same for all C-like languages). The following creates an infinite loop:

```
for (;;)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Of course, you could also accomplish this with a `while`-loop, as the other answers have suggested. Both solutions are perfectly valid and which one you choose is mostly a matter of style. In general, you should pick the solution which you find most clearly communicates to the reader what the code is trying to do.

Comment: Well it might not be an infinite loop, depending on what `//do stuff` does. It could contain a `break` statement that exits the loop.

Comment: @icemanind Correct. It's *as* infinite as `while (true) // do stuff`.

Comment: Why would you do this? It is easy overlook that it is no standard for loop and it has no longer the semantics of a for loop. That the variable scope is a bit tighter seems no good justification, too.

Comment: @DanielBrückner Any `for`-loop can be rewritten as a `while`-loop and vice-versa. IMHO, the difference between a `for`-loop and a `while`-loop is not just syntax, it's in the intent that it communicates. A `for`-loop expresses the idea of iterating through some process very regularly, one small step at a time, where you have a well known stopping point. A `while`-loop on the other hand expresses the idea that you will be continuing this process until a condition is met, but with much looser semantics. In other words, I think it depends on what `// do stuff` is. But as I said, both are valid.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop.

```
var i = 0;

while (i < whatever)
{
   // Do stuff including updating i.
}
```